# Why does experimental probability approach theoretical probability? Why does it converge only when there are large samples and not when it's small?

Tags: probability, statistics

I went through Khan Academy's lecture on [theoretical and experimental probability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nos-xOCpQqg). I also read through a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiment_(probability_theory)) article on this but was still not clear. I understand how it approaches (as explained in the video) but unable to understand why experimental probability approaches theoretical probability. What is the reason for this?

I think that the general sense is, if I take a large enough sample, I am going to end up getting the expected mean of the sample. The more experiments I do, the more it converges. Sure, I get that. But why does it converge only when there are large samples and not when it's small?

Comment: Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth: I think the OP is indirectly asking "why" the strong law of large numbers is correct. So an intuitive explanation of the proof of the strong law of large numbers (if that's possible) should suffice

Comment: I think that the general sense is, if I take a large enough sample, I am going to end up getting the expected mean of the sample. The more experiments I do, the more it converges. Sure, I get that. But why does it converge only when there are large samples and not when it's small?

Comment: @SudhanvaNarayana: It's better to edit your question accordingly. In its current state, it's not clear enough what you expect from an answer.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari I have edited. Please do check

Comment: The fluctuations that almost inevitable happen, are significant in the case of a small number of observations. If the number of observations gets bigger, the fluctuations are less and less significant. This phenomen is best described in the central limit theorem. I suggest that you carefully study this theorem.

Comment: One comment might be to think about smallest, i.e. take only one sample.

Comment: experimental results don't have to converge towards results predicted by probability.  You could toss a fair coin and keep getting heads indefinitely, but the probability that results do fall closer to expectation increases with the number of events.  For coin tosses it is possible to represent the expected percentage of heads as a histogram, showing convergence to 50% for large n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You think you are "unable to understand why experimental probability approaches theoretical probability". **We all are.** *Experimental probability* means really throwing physical coins or needles, or picking colored balls from an urn, and counting the various outcomes.

On the other hand *probability theory* is a mathematical edifice with the purpose to talk coherently about events and processes considered "random". Take throwing a coin as an example. At the beginning we only postulate that in a single throw we see $H$ or $T$ with equal probabilities ${1\over2}$, *whatever that means*. We then create the idea of *independence*. This entails that when throwing the coin $n$ times all $2^n$ binary strings over $\{H,T\}$have the same probability ${1\over2^n}$. In this model we don't know which string we shall observe, but we can **prove** that with high probability we see about ${n\over2}$ $H$s. This means that the model behaves in the way we intuitively think about probabilities. But the model then also has answers to more difficult questions, e.g., how often will we (on average) have to throw the coin in order to see a run of $10$ $H$s.

Concerning "convergence": This notion by its very name requires large numbers of "experiments" within our model. One then, e.g.,  **proves** that, for an infinite sequence of  coin throws, with probability $1$ the fraction of $H$s converges to ${1\over2}$. Again: Why this seems to be the case also when you throw a coin $10^6$ times in your lab, nobody knows.

But maybe other people think differently. There is a large literature about the "philosophy of probability".

Comment: Good answer! +1

Comment: Well, if we can prove that for a sufficiently large number of trials, the number of H s becomes $n/2$, doesn't it mean that the truth for experiments meeting theory after infinite experiments is embedded in the fact that we initially considered the coin to have $1/2$ probability of showing heads?

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar:  From the probability ${1\over2}$ for heads, the assumption of independence and the axioms of probability it is easy to prove mathematically that the limit in question is ${1\over2}$. But the  "philosophical" problem is: Why does the real physical coin behave like probability theory says?

Comment: *Because there is no reason why it has to favour one side more?*  I mean, I sense I am understanding it wrong altogether. You are talking in terms of philosophy, and I am talking in terms of what I think is axiomatic, thus subjecting me to prejudice? Would you like to educate me more?